# Input file and auto submit - Play framework 2

Tags: java, javascript, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I write an auto submit form (for file uploading)? I've tried to add `onchange` in `<input>` field:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <span class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
        <input type="file" name="file" onchange="@routes.Application.upload()"/>
        </span>
        <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
        <a href="#" class="close fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" style="float: none">&times;</a>

        <input class="btn btn-success btn-large"  type="submit" value="Submit!"> 

     </div>
    }
```

but it does not work. Any ideas? I'm using Play Framework 2 with Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check on your own eyes how does it look in the code. in your `onchange` attribute you put just an url, and for browser it has no sensible meaning.

Instead you should put there name of some JavaScript method to perform, ie:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
```